# download c compiler to ubuntu

Tags: 10.04

How can I download  PIC18 v3.38 in Lite mode as C-Compiler to Mplab ? I could not see any link to repository.

Can I download it with sudo apt-get install ?

Note : I am not using wine

```
   ubuntu 10.04
```

Comment: Just suggesting, your name (`gcc`) is a compiler too: "GNU C Compiler". It's available from the repositories. I suggest you to install `build-essential` which will pull in all possible helpful tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be correct: GCC stands for "GNU Compiler Collection" and does not compile binaries for PIC Microcontrollers.

The PIC18 compiler can be downloaded from the [MPLAB site](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en010014):

To my knowledge it is Windows only and does not work with Wine. You might have to use another compile such as the [HI-TECH C Compiler for PIC10/12/16](http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=1406&dDocName=en542849)

Also see [Programming PIC's in Linux](http://www.micahcarrick.com/pic-c-programming-linux.html).